# NpgSql, Failed to set Database.DefaultConnectionFactory when try to connect with Conection String

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

[DBContext Msdn Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx)

When I try to connect with the constructor that takes a ConStr parameter, the application throws exception below. But if I use the first constructor that takes no constr, connects successfully.

Thrown Exception Message:

> Failed to set Database.DefaultConnectionFactory to an instance of the
>   'Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql' type as specified in the application
>   configuration. See inner exception for details.

Inner Exception Message

> Constructor on type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory' not found.

```
Entity Framework - Version 6.1.3,
EntityFramework6.Npgsql - Version 3.1.1,
Npgsql - Version 3.1.7
```

Comment: Ever found a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, somewhere else, I have realised that I was disposing my dbcontext instance and recreate it unfortunately. This exception exactly tells that dbcontext could not reach the connectionstring specified. Or no connectionstring specified in config file.

Comment: Can we change it runtime, for.eg mssql to mysql or mysql to mssql ? [For reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998212/dynamically-change-update-setdefaultconnectionfactory-and-setproviderservices-en)

Comment: Did not try to change data source in runtime. But I think it would be ok to change.

Answer (score 1):

Include the following within your DbContext implementation namespace:

```
using Npgsql;
using System.Data.Entity;

class NpgSqlConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public NpgSqlConfiguration()
    {
        var name = "Npgsql";

        SetProviderFactory(providerInvariantName: name,
        providerFactory: NpgsqlFactory.Instance);

        SetProviderServices(providerInvariantName: name,
        provider: NpgsqlServices.Instance);

        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(connectionFactory: new NpgsqlConnectionFactory());
    }
}
```

Instantiate your context this way within your dependency injection or wherever you decide to create the context:

```
    MyDbContext _dbContext;
    var connectionString = Config.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionStringName");
    NpgsqlConnection connection = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
    _dbContext = new MyDbContext(connection);
```